# Is it possible to turn Ubuntu to elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation, system

I have Ubuntu 18 installed in my computer. I want to installed elementary OS. I kind started liking it. But I have so many apps installed in the Ubuntu installation and I don't want to lose those. So is there any of turning my Ubuntu to elementary OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, but will be painful and you'll probably lose time and data in the process. And definitively you'll break the system

Is better to save `/home` if you don't have it already in a separated mount point and then install elementary OS fresh. Create a list of the apps you use an want that way you can install them later and because you saved `/home` you will have all the settings as before

I will comment that I could be give you some pointers on how to do it, but I will not because I find that you'll probably hate elementary and go back to Ubuntu. You deserve the full and proper experience